# Atlanta Sitecore User Group - June 27, 2019

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**Date/Time (EST):** June 27, 2019, 6:30 p.m.

**Date/Time (UTC):** June 27, 2019, 23:30

**Location:** [Roam Buckhead](https://www.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=3365+Piedmont+Rd+NE,+Suite+1400,+Atlanta,+GA,+us), 3365 Piedmont Rd NE, Suite 1400, Atlanta, GA

**RSVP:** https://www.meetup.com/Atlanta-Sitecore/events/258465319/

**Twitter:** [@AtlantaSitecore](https://twitter.com/atlantasitecore)

[image: Atlanta Sitecore User Group]

Mark your calendars for the next Atlanta Sitecore User Group meeting on Thursday, June 27th, at 6:30 p.m., at [Roam in Buckhead](https://www.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=3365+Piedmont+Rd+NE,+Suite+1400,+Atlanta,+GA,+us)!

Parking will be complimentary. We will be providing prepaid validations to all our guests. Dinner and drinks will be served.

**Raffle**: [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/) has provided us with a [ReSharper Ultimate](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotnet/) license to give away. We will raffle that and two gift cards at the end of the event!

We are looking forward to a great meeting! Everyone is welcome and we encourage you to spread the word!

### Agenda

- 6:30 - 6:55: Food, drinks, and social time
- 6:55 - 7:00: [Corey Smith](https://twitter.com/sitecorey) ([Corey Smith Consulting](https://www.coreysmith.co)) - Sitecore Community Update
- 7:00 - 7:35: [Andy Uzik](https://twitter.com/AndyUzick) ([Arke](https://www.arke.com/)) - Sitecore Build Approaches: Which Way to Go? (With a Deeper Look at SXA)
- 7:35 - 8:10: [Mike Shaw](https://twitter.com/me_mikeshaw) ([Sitecore](https://www.sitecore.com/)) - What's coming in Sitecore 9.2
- 8:10 - 8:45: [Richard Seal](https://twitter.com/rich_seal) ([Perficient Digital](https://www.perficientdigital.com/)) - Optimize Your SXA FED Workflow
- 8:45: Closing comments, raffle, end of event

### Presentations

#### Sitecore Build Approaches: Which Way to Go? (With a Deeper Look at SXA)

**Speaker**: [Andy Uzik](https://twitter.com/AndyUzick) ([Arke](https://www.arke.com/))

- Sitecore supported build approaches (MVC, SXA, JSS)
- Balance of control and pace
- Comparing the cadence of the three approaches
- Use cases
- SXA: Deeper dive
- Understanding
- What's in the box?
- Organizational changes to project workflow
- Roles and Tasks

#### What's Coming in Sitecore 9.2

**Speaker**: [Mike Shaw](https://twitter.com/me_mikeshaw) ([Sitecore](https://www.sitecore.com/))

Sitecore Experience Platform 9.2 is fast approaching, join Mike as he debuts the new enhancements in the coming release. This first look into all the features will provide all the necessary information to review your upgrade.

#### Optimize Your SXA FED Workflow

**Speaker**: [Richard Seal](https://twitter.com/rich_seal) ([Perficient Digital](https://www.perficientdigital.com/))

SXA, Creative Exchange, How to optimize the front end workflow to make Creative Exchange work for you instead of against you.